# text declaration errror in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Little help required

I keep getting an error :

> "XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
>   Location: http://localhost/test/
>   Line Number 2, Column 1:"

in the inspector on Firefox it comes up with  ^

I know that the problem will be with the ^ but I can't seem to find any whitespaces in the below code.  Also in the source code the

Just to clarify I am trying to following the instructions here: [Using PHP's DOM XML functions to output XML](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps#domfunctions)

Any help is appreiciated.

Thanks

```
<?php
// require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
echo '<markers>';
$ind=0;
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'id="' . $row['id'] . '" ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
  $ind = $ind + 1;
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
?>
```

Comment: `echo "<marker "` ... methinks.

Comment: Note: you can [use `htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) instead of implementing it yourself (as `parseToXML`)

Comment: also, you should forget the use of "@some_function" ... error messages, exceptions, etc are your friend. .02

Comment: The XML error can only be spotted or even solved if you post the rendered markup. Use the "show source code" option in your browser and see if you can spot any obvious mistakes. If you can't see the error ata first glance, paste the XML in an editor with proper syntax highlighting or use an online XML parser with verbose error reporting.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Nope the part with the echos looks OK, it is the Markdown implementation on SO, that has syntax highlighting issues at that point. Nonetheless this is the worst method of creating XML files. One should definitely [use one of the PHP XML-libraries to avoid such errors in XML rendering](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php). (e.g. SimpleXML)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I tried closing the "<marker>" but same result.  I believe the whitespace is coming in at the very end of the </marker> but noting in my code shows it.

Comment: If this is an error shown by Firefox (and not your server), it's a problem of the generated XML file. Can you share that?

Comment: @NicoHaase do you mean what the Firefox page shows?

Comment: @feeela totally with you about creating xml with appropriate tools. However, if i try to edit OP's code, the space after the `marker` opening tag is not there, thus i expect browser receives <markerid=whatever .../>

Comment: @YvesLeBorg my mistake on the marker, has been editted in the code.  However I still get the same errorr.  here is he souce code I get from Firefox:  <sourcetext xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/xml/parsererror.xml">﷐&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;&lt;markers&gt;&lt;marker id="5" name="Test Name" address="Test Address" lat="-34.396999" lng="150.643997" /&gt;&lt;/markers&gt;
^﷯</sourcetext>

Comment: @feeela can you tell me what the a appropriate tool for the XML would be?  not a lot of experience debugging.